# Cloudera-scm-server.log showing error at two places

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to run `Cloudera-Manager` and it's giving me error given in following screenshots and marked with red pen.

[image]

[image]

Can anybody help me resolve those error ??

Comment: Please post code and log output not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite straightforward. Cloudera Manager can't connect to the database with credentials specified. Are you able to connect manually with credentials provided in /etc/cloudera-scm-server/db.properties?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 database is what I am using

Comment: Is it embedded postgres that comes with Cloudera Manager (cloudera-scm-server-db package) or external postgres you've installed yourself?

Comment: Its external one...And I am working in secure environment where internet connection is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its trying to find Driver class for Mysql DB (and not Postgres). I can see below error in your snapshot:

```
JDBC Driver Class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```